# Удаление из адреса файлов, которые заканчиваются на .php

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Вот есть функция:

```
public static function getfullurl() {
        $fullurl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
        if(preg_match("|/index\.php|i", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
            $fullurl = preg_replace("|/index\.php|i","",$fullurl);
        }
        return "http://".$fullurl;
    }
```

Собственно суть ее в том, чтобы удалить из адреса index.php

А мне нужно, чтобы она удаляла не только index.php, но и любые файлы, заканчивающиеся на .php.

Допустим, index1.php index2.php

В общем я попробовал ее так исправить, но она не подходит:

```
public static function getfullurl() {
        $fullurl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
        if(preg_match("|^/.+\.php$|i", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
            $fullurl = preg_replace("|^/.+\.php$|i","",$fullurl);
        }
        return "http://".$fullurl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в чем:

`/index\.php` ищет вот такой вот формат /index.php, а не непосредственно index.php, как заявлено у тебя. Да и заменяет тоже, с учетом /, учти это при реализации логики.

Для поиска любых файлов с расширением .php достаточно шаблона:

```
.+?\.php
```

[пример.](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/.%2B%3F%5C.php%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40index.php%20%262a%3Bindex1.php%20%262a%3Bindex2.php%20%20%262a%3Btest.php/)
Для поиска любых файлов по типу  index123.php достаточно шаблона:

```
index\d\.php
```

[пример 2.](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/index%5Cd%5C.php%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40index.php%20index1.php%20index2.php%20%20test.php/)

В твоем-же шаблоне, ошибка в реализации логики. Замени на

```
preg_match("|\/.+?\.php|i",...
```

[пример 3.](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/%5C%262f%3B.%2B%3F%5C.php%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%262f%3Bindex.php%262a%3B%262f%3Bindex1.php%20%262a%3B%262f%3Bindex2.php%20%20%262a%3B%262f%3Btest.php/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
|/\w+\.php|i
```

Comment: неа, в общем случае - [пример][1]


  [1]: http://www.pcre.ru/eval/%5C%262f%3B%5Cw%2B%5C.php%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%262f%3Btest-mod.php/

Comment: Тогда:

    /\/[a-z0-9._-]+\.php/i

В любом случае нужно отталкиваться от конкретной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getfullurl() {
    $url = preg_replace("|^(.*?)([^/]+\.php)?$|", '\\1', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    return "http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$url}";
}
```

Но это не сработает для url вида "http://example.com/foo/bar.php/foo" так-как в `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` будет "/foo/bar.php/foo". Возможно для таких случаев подойдет $_SERVER`['SCRIPT_NAME']`